# Fail compilation bcs of redundant variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

The problem that I have is that, after setting a variable with a certain name, in JavaScript IDE (WebStorm), the name of the variable is colored in gray and says: local variable "..." is redundant and so I can't compile.

This is an exercise example:

```
function sumOfNums(num1, num2, num3) {
    let sum = num1 + num2 + num3;
    return sum;
}
sumOfNums(5, 2, 3);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not clear what issue is?

Comment: Javascript is not compiled.  What are you talking about?

Comment: What variable? Which name?

Comment: *and so I can't compile* Explain this. You don't need to compile JavaScript.

Comment: It compiles but when after compilation I don't receive the answer written on the console(WebstormIDE). And I am talking about the name of the variable, in my case 'sum'

Comment: Just return `num1+num2+num3` and remove `sum` from function

Answer (score 0):

That error means the variable assignment is unnecessary as it is not used elsewhere other than the return. Simply returning immediately will remove that warning.

```
function sumOfNums(num1, num2, num3) {
    return num1 + num2 + num3;
}
```

Comment: But, it certainly would't prevent the code from running.

Comment: @ScottMarcus by compile, I'm under the assumption there's a build step that does linting (eslint or something) and won't proceed unless warnings are addressed.

Comment: But after removing the return how am I supposed to receive an answer on the console?

Answer (score 0):

you can omit `sum` like:

```
function sumOfNums(num1, num2, num3) {
    return num1 + num2 + num3;
}
```